# Undefined index image

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Alright , I have a little problem here , which tried to solve but didnt succeed,

I brought all the "Table" Members to the blade page But It still refuses to proccess the problem,

I get this error ,

Undefined index: image (in the view)

```
Here is the Controller ,



public function getProfile() {
           $m = self::$data['members'] = Members::all()->toArray();
            self::$data['title'] = 'Profile';
            return view('forms.profile', self::$data);
        }

//The blade 
       <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image:</label>
                <img border="0" class="img-circle" width="150" src="{{ asset('images/members-pictures/' . $members['image']) }}">
                <br><br>
                <input name="image" type="file"><br>
            </div>
I appreciate your help , thanks .
```

Comment: Are there any errors you are getting? Because it looks like you are getting an array with members, and then you try to echo an array element in blade which is not possible because there could be more entries in the array. Meaning you will have to loop through the member array first.

Comment: Yes sir , here's the error 
Undefined index: image
 When I do dd on the array It shows me all the users in the table .

Comment: Jordy , Yes I made a foreach but how can I specify the photo for the selected user ? because It prints all the pictures for all the users , I want just the one picture , thanks

Comment: You will need to use something along the lines of `Members::find(user_id_here)` instead of `Members::all`

Comment: Yes ,thanks , but when I use this way It says Missing argument 1

Answer (score 0):

$members is an array of items and you are trying to access it like it was a single item.

Your controller method is overcomplicated, it could be just:

```
public function getProfile() 
{
    return view('forms.profile', [
        'members' => Members:all()->toArray(),
        'title = 'Profile'
    ]);
}
```

And the blade template, depending on whether you are going to display one single member or a list of them:

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Image:</label>
            <img border="0" class="img-circle" width="150" src="{{ asset('images/members-pictures/' . $members[0]['image']) }}">
            <br><br>
            <input name="image" type="file"><br>
        </div>
```

Above code would show the first item from the $members array. If you want to iterate through the array – you could use @foreach ($members as $member) control structure, and replace $members[0] with $member.